# sed with regex not working as expected

Tags: sed, regular-expression

This is my first time attempting to use SED.

I can get the substitution command to work with simple strings. As in:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' file.txt
```

However when I attempt to use a Regex it stops working. The regex I want to use is trying to identify URLs:

```
(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

I am trying to remove all URLs from a text file. Here's my full command:

```
sed -i 's/(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)//g' file.txt
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add `-r` to your `sed` command to turn on extended regular expressions.

In a nutshell, without `-r`, `?`, `+`, `()`, `{}`, and `|` have literal meaning and you need to prefix them with a backslash to give them “regex” meaning.

See [the documentation on the GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE%20The%20doc) for a deeper explanation.